# How can I avoid unused fields just for Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#

Ok they technically aren't "unused", but they never get used by the class that holds them so I guess in a sense they are. Here is a hypothetical situation I am trying to find the answer to.

I have a class `NetworkListener`,

```
public NetworkListener(IPAddress ipAddress, int port, NetworkClientPacketRepository packetRepository)
```

NetworkListener at times has to create a new class, which is out of the composition root:

```
new NetworkClient(await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(), _packetRepository, _logger);
```

Is this bad practice? It feels like it, it looks like it, so it must be, right? I'm not sure,

A few things that stand out to me that show it is...

A. NetworkListener has to accept a `NetworkClientRepository` dependency just because `NetworkClient` needs it.

B. NetworkListener has to accept a `Logger` dependency just because `NetworkClient` needs it.

It seems wrong, but I don't know a better way, hence why I do it this way.

How can I avoid having unused fields just to pass into a child class?

Here is my composition root:

```
services.AddSingleton<NetworkEventArguments>();
services.AddSingleton<NetworkClientRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<Dictionary<int, IClientPacket>>();
services.AddSingleton<ClientPacketRepository>();
services.AddSingleton(provider => new NetworkListener(
    IPAddress.Parse(config.GetValue<string>("Networking:Host")),
    config.GetValue<int>("Networking:Port"),
    provider.GetService<NetworkClientRepository>()
));
```

NetworkListener class:

```
public class NetworkListener : IDisposable
{
    private readonly NetworkClientRepository _clientRepository;
    private readonly ClientPacketRepository _packetRepository;
    private readonly TcpListener _listener;

    public NetworkListener(IPAddress ipAddress, int port, NetworkClientRepository clientRepository, ClientPacketRepository packetRepository)
    {
        _clientRepository = clientRepository;
        _packetRepository = packetRepository;
        _listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
    }

    public void Start(int backlog = 100)
    {
        _listener.Start(backlog);
    }

    public async Task ListenAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            HandleIncomingConnection(await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync());
        }
    }
    
    public event EventHandler<NetworkEventArguments> ClientConnected;
    
    private void HandleIncomingConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        var networkClient = new NetworkClient(client, _packetRepository);
        
        _clientRepository.AddClient(networkClient);
        
        ClientConnected?.Invoke(this, new NetworkEventArguments
        {
            Client = networkClient
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _listener.Server.Close();
        _listener.Server.Dispose();
    }
}
```

NetworkClient class:

```
public class NetworkClient : IDisposable
{
    public TcpClient TcpClient { get; }
    
    private readonly ClientPacketRepository _packetRepository;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly NetworkStream _networkStream;

    public NetworkClient(TcpClient tcpClient, ClientPacketRepository packetRepository, ILogger logger)
    {
        TcpClient = tcpClient;
        
        _packetRepository = packetRepository;
        _logger = logger.ForContext<NetworkClient>();
        _networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        ProcessDataAsync();
    }
    
    private void ProcessDataAsync()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            // TODO: Read from tcpClient
        });
        
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        TcpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: When is the `NetworkClient` object created? During the constructor or at a later time?

Comment: Its created when the TcpListener has a new incoming connection.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am using `Microsoft.Extentions.DependencyInjection` but `NetworkClient` is a transient and gets created when TcpListener has a new connection. `NetworkListener` is inside my DI container.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've already realized that, my question was how can I avoid doing this.

Comment: Can you write a `NetworkClientFactory` which can be used to get a new `NetworkClient` object? You can inject this instance (which has all the dependencies already resolved), so you don't need the `ILogger` and `NetworkClientRepository` references anymore.

Comment: @Progman because then the issue is the same, the factory class has to create a packet repository and a logger instance for NetworkClient, and then NetworkListener still has to receive a factory instance that itself doesn't ever use, it seems this approach would spread the issue rather than fixing it.

Comment: The `NetworkListener` would actively use the `NetworkClientFactory` to get an object by calling a method like `BuildInstance(client);`. You are right that the "problem" have been move to a different class, but then `NetworkListener` doesn't need to know about the dependencies of `NetworkClient` anymore. There is a solution by using the `IServiceProvider` but this can turn into an anti-pattern "Service locator".

Comment: @Progman See the answer below, I have decided to go with the factory pattern. It does spread the problem, but it also isolates it to just the factory class, which IMO isn't so bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this bad practice? It feels like it, it looks like it, so it must be, right? I'm not sure,

It certainly is. Your classes should only instantiate data classes or third-party services that cannot be injected. Instantiating `TcpListener` is a good example of the latter.

Your problem arises from here:

```
public NetworkClient(TcpClient tcpClient, ClientPacketRepository packetRepository, ILogger logger)
```

Try to avoid having dependencies and 'data' mixed together in the constructor. Instead, let the constructor have only parameters that can be injected, and put the rest of the parameters in the appropriate methods.

Here's how `NetworkClient` should look like:

```
public interface INetworkClient 
{
    void ProcessDataAsync(TcpClient tcpClient);
}

public class NetworkClient : INetworkClient, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ClientPacketRepository _packetRepository;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public NetworkClient(ClientPacketRepository packetRepository, ILogger logger)
    {
        _packetRepository = packetRepository;
        _logger = logger.ForContext<NetworkClient>();
    }
    
    // this Async in the name and the Thread being created internally looks smelly
    private void ProcessDataAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

You could then have a `NetworkClientFactory` class that just generates a new instance of `NetworkClient`, and you'd inject this factory into `NetworkListener`.

```
public interface INetworkClientFactory
{
    INetworkClient Create();
}

public class NetworkClientFactory : INetworkClientFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public NetworkClientFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    // getting a specific service like this is normally considered an anti-pattern, 
    // however, it's generally accepted in factories when the DI system doesn't provide better ways
    public INetworkClient Create() => 
       _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<INetworkClient>();
}
```

So you'd use this with:

```
private void HandleIncomingConnection(TcpClient client)
{
    var networkClient = _networkClientFactory.Create();
    netowrkClient.ProcessDataAsync(client);
    
    _clientRepository.AddClient(networkClient);
    
    ClientConnected?.Invoke(this, new NetworkEventArguments
    {
        Client = networkClient
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to spread the issue rather than solving it, the factory still needs to get the logger instance from the DI container somehow.

Comment: Not really, the factory just needs to get a transient instance from DI

Comment: Can you include an example of that in your answer? Otherwise I am stuck in the same place I was before, not knowing how to instantiate a class inside a class, and how to get said dependencies for that class without storing them in the class creating the new class. I am using Serilog.

Comment: On the create method, how can I pass a non DI instance, such as the TcpClient? I don't think I can get this from the DI as it comes from NetworkListener.

Comment: You shouldn't do that in the first place. `_serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<INetworkClient>()` returns a new NetworkClient instance, you can continue configuring from there

Comment: So property inject it instead of constructor injection? This opens up the property to be mutable, which doesn't sound good.

Comment: It's as simple as there is no 'good' way of passing that kind of data in the constructor. The only way would be to retrieve the services in the factory and manually create the instance, which puts you exactly where you were in the question

Comment: So just so I got this right, my only option is to use `_serviceProvider`, and build `NetworkClient`'s constructor using the GetServer method for each dependency for the constructor? If this is the case then at least the problem is isolated to just the factory, which is an improvement.

Comment: That's one way, yes, but I'm not sure I understand why the code as presented wouldn't work for you

Comment: Because there is no way to pass in the TcpClient which comes from `_listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()` into `NetworkClient`'s constructor. I think building it like `return new NetworkClient(client, 
                _serviceProvider.GetService<ClientPacketRepository>(), 
                _serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger>());` is the only option, or using ActivatorUtilities for less code but the same approach.

Comment: Well, that's exactly why `networkClient.ProcessDataAsync(client);` is being called. You either need to look at this differently or tell us exactly what you need

Comment: But `ProcessDataAsync` gets called by `NetworkClient` (I should of made `ProcessDataAsync` private to make that clear apologies) which means `NetworkClient` still needs the client, it also has to dispose it so it will have to be part of `NetworkClient`. The issue with your answer is, it doesn't allow `NetworkClient` to receive the `TcpClient` instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223241/discussion-between-camilo-terevinto-and-aaa).